# Bulk delete files from FileField/ImageFields across many records

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a model called `Picture` which has an ImageField field `picture_file`.

I'm using post_delete signals to remove the file from the filesystems as `Picture`s are deleted:

```
def delete_picture(sender, **kwargs):
    picture_file = kwargs.get('instance')
    picture.picture_file.storage.delete(picture.picture_file.path)
post_delete.connect(delete_picture, Picture)
```

However bulk deletes don't trigger post delete signals, so instead for bulk_deletes I'd like to gather all the paths and delete in a single operation. Is this possible, and would a single delete operation even be beneficial in this instance?

The storage method should be identical for all files so if there's a bulk file deletion command/module I think that would be ideal?

Comment: Django do emit `post_delete` signal on bulk delete.

Comment: So I keep reading, however that is not the case for me. I run: `Picture.objects.all().delete()` and my logger outputs debug code per row for the `post_delete` signal. If I disconnect the signal first however, the `all().delete()` then runs the bulk delete in a single SQL query. So essentially the post_delete signal forces the bulk_delete to run row by row, negating the performance improvement I'm striving for. I'm not sure if that is a new or old Django feature you're referring to, but I'm using 1.4.

Comment: `post_delete` signal is just a signal and does not consume any query. Also it is not a good idea to delete all the files in a batch from the system. Think of a scenario the bulk delete failed in between then all of your files are lost. Rather i will suggest write a management command (which run periodically) which will delete orphaned files from system time to time if the file is not associated with any entry in db.

Comment: Hmmm good point on the background deletion. My issue with using `post_signal` is that it's presence appears to prevent a delete from being a single SQL DELETE, instead forcing each record to have a separate query. Perhaps instead I can disconnect the post_delete, loop through each picture and run the storage delete, then finally run the SQL DELETE from a single statement afterwards. I'll have a play with `timeit` and report back.

Answer (score 0):

Concept of bulk deletion is do it with effecity, so it will newer run any signals or additional methods.

You can easly change your manager, that before bulk deletion, you get all paths to remove, and then remove the files (or put this list for your celery or cron workers) and then remove objects from database, something like this:

```
class MyManager(models.Manager)
     def delete_with_files(self, **kwargs):
          qs = self.get_query_set().filter(**kwargs)
          files = list(qs.values_list('picture_file__path', flat=True))
          delete_all_files(files)
          qs.delete()
```

Answer (score 0):

Well this isn't quite the answer I'm looking for, but it's the solution I'm happy with until something better comes along:

Instead of calling:

```
Picture.objects.all().delete()
```

Which in turn calls the following post_delete signal for each row:

```
def delete_picture(sender, **kwargs):
    picture_file = kwargs.get('instance')
    picture.picture_file.storage.delete(picture.picture_file.path)
```

I instead disconnect the signal and then remove the files in a loop, and then run the bulk_delete after:

```
signals.post_delete.connect(delete_picture, sender=Picture)

pics = Picture.objects.all()
for pic in pics:
    signals.post_delete.connect(delete_picture_files, sender=PictureFile)
pics.delete()
```

Using `timeit`, on a single run of 500 records/files, this drops from `34` to `1.6` seconds.